# How to use Google Cloud Messaging from Google App Engine without consuming limited quotas?

Tags: sockets, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging, urlfetch

I am developing a messaging app, using Google App Engine (GAE) and Google Cloud Messaging (GCM). GCM has no usage limits, but calling its API from my backend in GAE, uses the URLFetch API, which has a daily limit of 172,800,000 calls. I like thinking big: If I had 200 million users, not all of them would be able to send just one message.

I have tried using Apache HttpClient instead of the GCM provided sender class, but it uses sockets internally, consuming the Google API Sockets instead, which has a daily limit of 663,552,000. My imaginary 200 million users could just send 3 messages each...

So, is there any way to call the GCM API from GAE that don't consume any hard capped quota?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered waiting until you get to, say, 5 million users before working out how you'd scale it x40? I applaud thinking big, but typically the right solution for 200 million users is the *wrong* solution for (say) 100,000 users.

Comment: Thanks @jon, for your fast reply, and for pointing it out. I have considered it indeed. All this effort could lead nowhere if I just get 10 users... But I am trying to solve any critical problems in advance. In case there is no workaround for this, I could be forced to change my backend to other platform. I think it would be better doing that now, without customer's pressure.
I am probably too concerned, but knowing that those limits won't ruin my project would let me sleep deeper.

Comment: If GCM supports bulk messaging in a single API call you could use [pull queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-pull) to hold and send messages. Your app would add messages to the queue and then a dedicated task would read from the queue and send every x messages or after a set timer.

Comment: You'd probably call up your customer service representative on your gold plan and explain the "problem" to them! :)

Comment: Josh: Good idea, but, as far as I know, GCM do not provide bulk messaging (except for sending the same message to multiple contacts). So, every message will make at least one URLFetch call.
Paul: I considered that option too. In GAE's documentation, it states that I can request higher throughput limits (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#When_a_Resource_is_Depleted). 
I guess all of you are right, and I am too much worried about an easily solvable problem, that I might not have to face! (However, I would like to be in that situation someday!)
Thank you everyone.